# How to automate a segue using Storyboard feature in iOS 5?

Tags: ios

I am trying to learn about Storyboards feature in iOS 5. I have this app that presents a EULA view with an accept button the first time it opens. The app remembers that the user accepted the EULA, and does not show it again. It shows another view (a tab bar view) as the first view from that point on. Can this be accomplished with storyboards? So far, I am only able to use a segue for user controlled actions. Where do I put the logic of checking the preferences to see if the user accepted the EULA and picking which UI View controller to show next, using one storyboard for the whole app? Hope this is clear.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can check your setting in your main view or in the app delegate using `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Once you have decided which view to display, you can transition to that view using `-performSegueWithIdentifier:`.